My window wells contain a mixture of rock and dirt. Should I remove it before filling with gravel?
My window wells contain a mixture of rock and dirt. I get weeds growing in them quite often. I put down some landscape fabric to deter the weeds. I am about to top the fabric with pea gravel, but I'm wondering if I should try and remove the dirt first. I assume the bottom of the window wells have gravel, but I don't know what the previous owners did. I think throwing in some gravel will be relatively harmless. I just don't want to be digging gravel out after I lay it in!

There used to be window well covers made from plastic.  Kept out dirt/soil/rain from getting in.  Very little stuff will stop weeds/vegetation from growing, they will only slow it down.  Dirt might slow down drainage.

Landscape fabric does not prevent weeds.  As for adding material to window wells that are already "full of" other stuff, might as well just remove the window if you're filling the well with anything but light and air - the point of the thing is lost if it's filled with dirt, rocks, or gravel. If that's not what you mean, then you need to [edit] to clarify what you do mean, because it is what you said.

@Ecnerwal I edited the question to be more clear. I was under the impression landscape fabric stopped weeds. What is for then? It is holding dirt in place?

The better grades of geotextile help keep gravel/stone and soil under the gravel stone from mixing (so the gravel/stone does not get "eaten" by soft soil under it due to traffic and frost movement.) Low end stuff is likely to tear. The alleged weed barrier marketing is pretty much organic fertilizer sourced from a male bovine. Weeds will, if nothing else, sprout on top of it and grow roots through it.

@Ecnerwal Ah, this matches the researching I did after you replied to my question. I'm learning all the time. Thank you. I'll have to share "organic fertilizer sourced from a male bovine" ;)

Short answer, yes. Depending on your annual rainfall and the depth of the eaves on your house, you should keep the medium in the window wells below the level of your basement windows and make sure they have a medium like gravel that drains good.
Over the years window wells fill with leaves and other matter that decomposes and builds up the level in the well. (that is why they sell the covers) This leads to water from rainfall not draining properly and possibly leaking through the window itself into your basement.
Dig out the wells a few inches below the level of the window and fill with a layer of gravel and keep the level below the window.
Proper drainage is the first step to a dry basement.

Suppose I dig down a foot and there is no gravel or rock, just dirt. Should I keep digging or is that a sufficient depth to start adding gravel?

That would be way plenty. 6-8" would also be good especially if you have never had water come in the windows. Then put your pea gravel or crushed stone in. If you get a lot of leaves in them they need to be cleaned out each year to keep them from decomposing and building up a mulch layer.

I appreciate the reply. I intend to dig as you've instructed and add in gravel. I am now considering window well covers as well.
